# How to create an edge style in tikz with a crossing in the middle and a label near it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I wonder how to recreate an edge between nodes in Petri Nets using tikz that would look like this:

[image: Figure 2.18 from Discrete, Continuous, and Hybrid Petri Nets by David, René, Alla, Hassane]

I played with different options yet cant get it wright.

A minimal code sample I am trying to integrate it into would look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,shapes,automata,petri,positioning}
\tikzset{
    place/.style={
        circle,
        thick,
        draw=black!75,
        %fill=white!20,
        minimum size=6mm,
    },
    transitionV/.style={
        rectangle,
        thick,
        fill=black,
        minimum height=8mm,
        inner xsep=2pt
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.4cm and 1cm,>=stealth',bend angle=45,auto]
    \node [transitionV,label=above:$T_1$] (t1) {};
    \node [place,tokens=1,label=above:$P_2$] (p2) [right=of t1] {}
        edge[pre]   (t1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which produces an image like this:

[image]

Yet I can not get how to create an edge style in tikz with a crossing in the middle and a label near it alike one on the first figure (selected in red)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a decoration style like

```
    markedge/.style={
    decoration={ markings,
      mark=at position .5 with {\draw[-,thick] (-2mm,2mm) -- (2mm,-2mm)node[inner sep=1pt,pos=0.5,auto]{#1};}  %% adjust 2mm etc as you wish
    },
    postaction={decorate}
  },
```

and then use it like

```
....edge[pre,markedge={2}]   (t1);
```

This needs `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,shapes,automata,petri,positioning,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
    place/.style={
        circle,
        thick,
        draw=black!75,
        %fill=white!20,
        minimum size=6mm,
    },
    transitionV/.style={
        rectangle,
        thick,
        fill=black,
        minimum height=8mm,
        inner xsep=2pt
    },
    markedge/.style={
    decoration={ markings,
      mark=at position .5 with {\draw[-,thick] (-2mm,2mm) -- (2mm,-2mm)node[inner sep=1pt,pos=0.5,auto]{#1};}  %% adjust 2mm etc as you wish
    },
    postaction={decorate}
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.4cm and 1cm,>=stealth',bend angle=45,auto]
    \node [transitionV,label=above:$T_1$] (t1) {};
    \node [place,tokens=1,label=above:$P_2$] (p2) [right=of t1] {}
        edge[pre,markedge={2}]   (t1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to add a label to it?

Comment: @DuckQueen Sorry, I missed that part. See the edit.